# How to understand memory allocation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, memory, android-studio, allocation

It seems that memory allocation of my application is not good as it could be. Therefore I tried to analyze, what is going on. I made dump and open it. But I don´t understand, what it means. It seems that FastPrintWriter is big source of memory allocation, but I have no idea what it is and where to find it. Is there any guide or something I can use to understand more to this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most probable cause for this is enabled GPU monitor while tracking Memory allocation. Try pausing GPU monitor and it should run fine. At least, that's what sorted out same issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, FastPrintWriter is a class used by Android internally. I found the source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/util/FastPrintWriter.java

It turns out that your code keeps calling dumpGfxInfo(). Each call allocates a FastPrintWriter. After some research, I think that your issue is actually a bug with Android Studio. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.0 Preview 7.